# Keep form focus

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms, user-interface

Ok, this may look like a previous asked question, but I already googled this and search here, and haven't found any answer.

I want a child form to open with the press of a button, and while is opened, I want to block access to the container until is closed. There's also the case in which when I open a form (F1) from the container, I can open another (F2) from F1. The idea is the same, while F2 is opened, the container is blocked and F1 is blocked as well, until I close it.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Form.ShowDialog` instead of `Form.Show`.

Answer (score 4):

ShowDialog() ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39wcs2dh(v=vs.80).aspx